# Why should users not use the same browser for both I2P and Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, i2p, information-leaks

In several forums and articles that I have read people say that the best security for users that want to run both Tor and I2P is to use separate browsers for each. What are the security and anonymity risks of configuring the Tor Browser Bundle to also work with I2P? Would some of this possible Tor/I2P-leaks be negated if the user disabled Firefox cache, cookies, and/or javascript?

Comment: I _think_ the reason for this is to prevent you from being tracked if your anonymity is compromised on one of the two networks.

Your browser has a fingerprint that could theoretically be used to identify you. Things such as what javascripts you block or cookies you accept.
If your anonymity is compromised on I2P (or Tor) your browser fingerprint could be linked to your identity, and hence used to de-anonymise you when you use the other (safe) anonymity network.

The Tor browser might not be weak against this though, since the devs design to protect against it.

Answer (score 6):

The recommended way to browse the web through Tor is to use the [Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html). Using any other browser will make you different from the common anonymity set of Tor users.

Changing the configuration of the Tor Browser is not recommended exactly for the same reason: it is likely to make the browser behave differently from everyone else's.

Tails include a browser which supports both Tor and I2P using FoxyProxy. See the [design document](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/I2P/) for more information. As Tails' user form their own anonymity set, it's a way to use both protocols in a single browser.

Comment: "_We are very sad to announce that Tails 2.11 will be the last version to include I2P, an alternative anonymizing network. [...] But we will be happy to reintroduce I2P if we find a volunteer to take care of maintaining it in Tails._"  https://tails.boum.org/news/version_2.11/index.en.html